# Failed to load the resource:server responded with a status 404

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Im working on a DynamicWebProject in Eclipse IDE.I got an error in console while running a jsp page showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".I already referred many questions regarding this problem but could not resolve it.Here is my javascript file

availability.js

```
var ajaxRequest = null;
if (window.activeXObject) {
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.HTTP");
} else {
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
function ajaxValidation() {
    var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/SpringHibernateProject/validate?name=" + name,
            true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            var message = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>"
                    + message + "</font>";
        }
    };

    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Here is my jsp page

AjaxPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/availability.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"  onkeyup="ajaxValidation()"></input>
<div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im getting this error though I referred the script file correctly.Why is it so?

Comment: 404 means file not found.check the location

Comment: yes,I did.The referrence made here is right.

Comment: what is your jsp page name?

Comment: But in the above code you have not mentioned ajapage.jsp anywhere

Comment: @JqueryLearner Here is my folder structure https://www.dropbox.com/s/okw16ml3tp8ih8f/FolderStruct.png

Comment: in the code where are you calling ajaxpage.jsp,show me the code

Comment: Im not calling AjaxPage.jsp anywhere rather than that Im running that page on tomcat server directly which has a javascript file reference to validate the input in ajaxpage.@JqueryLearner

Comment: well I dont understand what you are trying to do.Well what is validate in this /SpringHibernateProject/validate

Comment: Are you sure the path '/SpringHibernateProject/validate' is exists?

Comment: yes..It does @edisonthk